# Using for loop to set pinMode

Tags: code-optimization

I notice problems with my output pins when I use this method of setting their `pinMode`:

```
int allOutputPins[] = {3, 4, 9, 10, 5, A3, 11, 12, 7, 8, A1, A2};


for(int a = 0; a < sizeof(allOutputPins); a++){
   pinMode(allOutputPins[a], OUTPUT); 
  }//end for
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re  “Am I doing something wrong?”, yes :)

The `sizeof(allOutputPins)` expression returns the size of `allOutputPins[]` in terms of bytes, so is 24 because the array contains 12 two-byte integers.  The loop's last 12 `pinMode()` calls will be garbage.

Among other ways of fixing the problem, you could change the expression to `sizeof(allOutputPins)/sizeof(int)` [which has the same value, 12, as `(sizeof allOutputPins)/sizeof(int)`; eg see the syntax entries for the [sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) at cppreference.com] or you could change the base type of the array to `byte` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: I would recommend using `sizeof allOutputPins / sizeof allOutputPins[0]` instead. This idiom is more robust because it works independently of the type of the array. I would use it even if I change `allOutputPins` base type to `uint8_t`.

Comment: What you needed and were expecting was the count of the items in the array. I need this so regularly, I keep a _countof_ macro, `#define countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))` in my `local.h` file (personal file of common idioms).

Comment: Thanks @JRobert that's a good idea. Is that all I need to define to use it?

Comment: You also need to *use* the `countof` define like this: `for(int a = 0; a < countof(allOutputPins); a++){`

Comment: You would need to `#include <local.h>` in your sketch (the Arduino IDE won't know to do it for you); thereafter you can use it anywhere in your sketch, such as how @NickGammon just described.